# congruence modular forms have a basis with integral coefficients

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

I am looking for a proof of the following statement:

The complex vector space of holomorphic functions $f$ on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$ satisfying

(1) $f$ is modular of some integral weight with respect to a congruence subgroup $\Gamma \subset \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (i.e. $\Gamma$ contains the principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma(N)$ for some $N$)

(2) $f$ is meromorphic at the cusps of $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$

has a basis consisting of functions $f$ whose Fourier coefficients at infinity are algebraic integers.

Could anyone point out a reference or explain roughly how the proof goes?

Comment: Are you sure this statement is true in this generality? This makes sense for the space of modular cuspidal forms (perhaps with an assumption on $\Gamma$), but it is not trivial so in this generality I have no ideas or intuitions.

Comment: This is proved in Shimura's "Introduction to the arithmetic theory of automorphic functions".

Comment: Where exactly? Thanks